# daterangepicker and codeigniter form not working

Tags: forms, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using an example of bootstrap-datetimepicker in my codeigniter project.
I create a form with only the datetimepicker input.

view:

```
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    
$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('/calendario/nadevent/', $attributes); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="reservationtime">Fecha:</label>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="reservationtime" id="reservationtime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('reservationtime') ?>" />
    </div>

</div>

<?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit','class="btn btn-default"'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

JS:

```
 $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss', timePicker12Hour: false, separator: '/'});
```

The datepicker works fine but when i submit the form, I want to format the data and split into an array:

Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('reservationtime', 'reservationtime', '');
$array  = explode('/',set_value('reservationtime'));
```

Then I try to insert the values:

```
form_data = array(
    'start' => $array[0],
    'end' => $array[1]
;
```

But if I print the array, its empty:

```
Array ( [start] => [end] => )
```

Wha'ts wrong with the code?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You are using a daterangepicker, not a datetimepicker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really not getting data from your form, can you dump the $_POST?

Comment: Thanks, if I print the post:
Array ( [reservationtime] => 14-08-2014 12:00:00/14-08-2014 12:30:00 [submit] => Submit )
It show the values...

Comment: From your controller, try changing your code into this:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('reservationtime', 'reservationtime', '');
 $array  = explode('/',$_POST['reservationtime']);

Comment: Good for you =) Welcome. you have to use $_POST if you wanna get something from the form